# Is there any way to aggregate points within a certain distance of eachother into groups of X?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I know it's possible to aggregate points within a certain distance of each other, but is it also possible to aggregate them into groups of e.g. 20?

I'm fine with using most open source GIS software or ArcGIS.

Comment: What should your aggregation result look like (e.g. a polygon delineating the groups, a table with a aggregation classification field...etc)?

Comment: Let's say that there are 40 points that each have a value of 1. I then want those 40 points to be aggregated into two points that each have a value of 20. 

Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: Generally .. ofc it's possible. In this case? Still too little to go on.

Comment: Might want to take a look at the [Grouping Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p00000051000000) tool in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst. That combined with Mean/Median center might get what you want - it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do in your question, beyond aggregate on both a distance and number of points.

Comment: Selecting things within a tolerance of a single feature is straight forward (select by location, and count the features). But doing something with it ie which point do you aggregate everything to. Chris W might be right, count your features divide them by groups of 20 and then for the number of groups use the Group Analysis to define the centers of clusters and then use that to select the center most point.

Comment: I think you should focus your question on one GIS product, otherwise you are effectively asking multiple questions (one per product) which the [Tour] says not to do.